# How to make Scala Power Pack for IntelliJ Idea to work?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've installed Scala, SBT and Scala Power Pack plugins for IntelliJ Idea 9. And it says

"Plugin scala power pack failed to initialize and will be disabled:
scala/collection/VectorLike
Please restart IntelliJ IDEA"

I've found this with Google but with no solution. Do you know one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala Power Pack has been in a development haitus, but I hope to have an update available by the end of the year to work with Scala 2.8 and IDEA 9.0.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Now IDEA 10.5 and Scala 2.9 are out, yet no update is present.
However, automated conversion from Java to Scala (a major feature mentioned in the description) has been integrated in the main "Scala" plugin, so hopefully this plugin is not needed any more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Scala" plugin and the "SBT" plugin - they work great.

There is a nice writeup on how to set up projects with IDEA and SBT:
http://heikoseeberger.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-setup-scala-project-with-sbt-and.html

Comment: Thanks, Johan, good link, I am going follow your advice and do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's a plugin which hasn't been updated since a long time and before IntelliJ 9 was out. You can still try to contact the developer.

Comment: Dave Griffith is active here, so soon / by now, he will be / is aware of Ivan's inquiry.